# MooseX::Types coercions and $self

Tags: perl, moose, moosex-types

Is there anyway to get `$self` into a `MooseX::Types` coercion? I have other data in the object that I want to use to seed my coercion from a `String` to an `Object`. Alternatively, is there anything like `Class::MOP`'s `initializer` that will permit me to do this -- it would have to fire *before* the type checks.

Requested pseudo code:

```
with 'DBHandle';
has 'database' => ( isa => 'Str', is => 'ro', default => 'Db' );
has 'schema' => ( isa => 'Str', is => 'ro', default => 'schema' );
has 'table' => ( isa => 'Str', is => 'ro', default => 'column );

has 'columns' => ( isa => DBCols, is => 'ro', default => sub {[qw/foo bar baz/]} );
```

Here, I want "columns" to coerce to a `DBCols` -- an ArrayRef of DBCol's (objects) -- requiring the use of `catalog`, `schema`, and `col` attributes found in the class, and with a dbh/singleton provided by `DBHandle`.

To make this less-pseudo, the actually situation is only slightly more complex. I was able to accomplish the above with `around`, now what I want I to do is create an attribute trait that would permit this syntax:

```
has 'column_id' => (
  isa => Int
  , is => 'ro'
  , traits => ['DBKey']
  , default => 5
  , column => 'foo'
);
```

Where the attribute trait `column` provided by `DBKey`, coerces to `DBCol` the same way that the above `columns` would: this would require the ability to access the classes `database`, `schema`, `table`, and again the singleton for the `dbh`.

Comment: Can you give a pseudocode example of what you mean?

Comment: updated with pseudocodes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  It'd be nice, but coercions are really designed to be global, and no one has written a "context-sensitive coercion" yet, because no one's really sure how to.  (Actually, s/coercions/type constraints/ -- it'd be useful just to say "this Str must be a valid column name, defined as an entry in this object's `columns` HashRef".)

People usually solve this problem with `around` and/or some combination of `BUILD` and `BUILDARGS`.

Comment: Actually, that's really close what to what I'm trying to do. I just can't find a decent way to do it.

Comment: I figured.  That's what everyone always wants to do.  There's just no way to within the current type constraint system, AFAIK, because of its fundamental assumptions.

Comment: I've accepted this - I think "you can't" is right this time around, however depressing it might be.